# Error when trying to tune MLPClassifier hidden_layer_sizes using BayesSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, mlp, bayessearchcv

When trying to tune the sklearn **MLPClassifier hidden_layer_sizes** hyper parameter, using **BayesSearchCV**, I get an error: `ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar`.

However, when I use **GridSearchCV, it works great!** What am I missing?

Here goes a reproducible example:

```py
from skopt import BayesSearchCV
from skopt.space import Real, Categorical, Integer
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

X, y = load_iris(True)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,
                                                 train_size=0.75,
                                                 random_state=0)
# this does not work!
opt_bs = BayesSearchCV(MLPClassifier(), 
                     {'learning_rate_init': Real(0.001, 0.05),
                        'solver': Categorical(["adam", 'sgd']), 
                        'hidden_layer_sizes': Categorical([(10,5), (15,10,5)])}, 
                     n_iter=32,
                     random_state=0)

# this one does :)
opt_gs = GridSearchCV(MLPClassifier(), 
                   {'learning_rate_init': [0.001, 0.05],
                        'solver': ["adam", 'sgd'], 
                        'hidden_layer_sizes': [(10,5), (15,10,5)]})
                   
# executes optimization using opt_gs or opt_bs
opt = opt_bs
res = opt.fit(X_train, y_train)
opt
```

Produces:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-78e6d29cae99> in <module>()
     27 # executes optimization using opt_gs or opt_bs
     28 opt = opt_bs
---> 29 res = opt.fit(X_train, y_train)
     30 opt

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/skopt/searchcv.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, callback)
    678                 optim_result = self._step(
    679                     X, y, search_space, optimizer,
--> 680                     groups=groups, n_points=n_points_adjusted
    681                 )
    682                 n_iter -= n_points

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/skopt/searchcv.py in _step(self, X, y, search_space, optimizer, groups, n_points)
    553 
    554         # convert parameters to python native types
--> 555         params = [[np.array(v).item() for v in p] for p in params]
    556 
    557         # make lists into dictionaries

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/skopt/searchcv.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    553 
    554         # convert parameters to python native types
--> 555         params = [[np.array(v).item() for v in p] for p in params]
    556 
    557         # make lists into dictionaries

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/skopt/searchcv.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    553 
    554         # convert parameters to python native types
--> 555         params = [[np.array(v).item() for v in p] for p in params]
    556 
    557         # make lists into dictionaries

ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, BayesSearchCV accepts only parameters in Categorical, Integer, or Real type values. In your case, there is no issue w.r.t `learning_rate_init` and `solver` parameters as they are clearly defined as `Real` and `Categorical` respectively, the problem comes in the `hidden_layer_sizes` where you have declared the number of neurons as `Categorical` values which in this case are tuples, and BayesSearchCV is not yet equipped to handle search spaces in tuples, refer [here](https://github.com/scikit-optimize/scikit-optimize/issues/926) for more details on this. However, as a temporary hack, you could just create your own wrapper around MLPClassifier to make the parameters of the estimator be recognized properly. Please refer to the following code snippet for a sample:

```
from skopt import BayesSearchCV
from skopt.space import Integer
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor, MLPClassifier
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin
import itertools

X, y = load_iris(True)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,
                                                 train_size=0.75,
                                                 random_state=0)

class MLPWrapper(BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin):
    def __init__(self, layer1=10, layer2=10, layer3=10):
        self.layer1 = layer1
        self.layer2 = layer2
        self.layer3 = layer3

    def fit(self, X, y):
        model = MLPClassifier(
            hidden_layer_sizes=[self.layer1, self.layer2, self.layer3]
        )
        model.fit(X, y)
        self.model = model
        return self

    def predict(self, X):
        return self.model.predict(X)

    def score(self, X, y):
        return self.model.score(X, y)


opt = BayesSearchCV(
    estimator=MLPWrapper(),
    search_spaces={
        'layer1': Integer(10, 100),
        'layer2': Integer(10, 100),
        'layer3': Integer(10, 100)
    },
    n_iter=11
)

opt.fit(X_train, y_train)
opt.score(X_test,y_test)
0.9736842105263158
```

Note: This assumes that you build an MLP network with three layers. You can modify it as per your need. Also, it becomes slightly tricky to create a class that constructs any MLP with an arbitrary number of layers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I just wanted to set the layer sizes as 'categorical' for the optimizer to choose one of the 2 options provided (as grid search does), and do the proper bayes search with the "numerical hyper parameters". Well ... I did not realize the Categorical class only works with strings! Thanks again :)